# Applying where condition to each value selected in Linq query with Groupby in it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

In this linq query I need to apply where condition for selecting only tiertype .I have tried the following but getting error in the where condition of tiertype.The error is "ti in ti.ImageVersion ti does not exist in current context.

```
var result = (from p in _context.Product
                          join ti in _context.TierImageMap on p.Id equals ti.ProductId
                          join t in _context.Tiers on ti.TierType equals t.Id

                          where (p.Id == productname)
                          orderby ti.ReleaseVersion descending

                          group new { ti, t } by new { ti.ImageName, t.TierType,ti.ImageVersion } into cities


                          select new
                          {

                              ReleaseVersion = string.Join(",", (from n in cities select n.ti.ReleaseVersion).Distinct().Take(3)),
                              ImageName = string.Join(",", (from n in cities select n.ti.ImageName).Distinct()),
                              TierType = string.Join(",", (from n in cities select n.t.TierType).Where(ti.ImageVersion== imageversion).Distinct())

                              //String.Format(ti.ReleaseVersion, ", ").GroupBy.OrderByDescending( ti.ImagDESeName ) as Releaseversion,
                              //String.Format(t.TierType, ", ").GroupBy.OrderByDescending( ti.ImageName ) as Tiertype



                          }).ToList().Distinct();

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Please share Product, TierImageMap and Tiers models

Comment: ImageVersion exists in TierImageMap table